# How to group data into tables in Google Sheets App Script using Batch Operating technique with Array to improve execution time?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, batch-processing

As described in google app script documentation, to improve performance, it is recommended to perform batch operating by using arrays so that the time for data reading and writing can be reduced significantly with the help of setValues(Array), setFontWeights(Array),setHorizontalAlignments(Array) functions.

I wonder how to set the borders using this technique, as there is no setBorders(Array) function.

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: There is no `setBorders`. If that is a significant part of your code, use advanced Google services or Google sheets api. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for  official documentation,  **benchmarks**.

Comment: @TheMaster, thank you for warning me. I wonder if it is okay if the email is exclusively used for sharing documents here in stackoverflow.

Comment: It is ok for your privacy, but still any questions that depend on external links don't benefit the community and some users won't even click it.

Comment: @TheMaster okay, I will use table instead. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to quickly set borders, enable sheet api service and adapt the following script (this is an example)

```
function setBorderCells() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
  bordersUpdating(ss.getId(), sh.getSheetId(), 2, 6, 7, 8)
}
function bordersUpdating(id, gid, startRow, endRow, startColumn, endColumn) {
  const resource = {
    "requests": [
      {
        "updateBorders": {
          "range": {
            "sheetId": gid,
            "startRowIndex": +startRow - 1,
            "endRowIndex": +endRow,
            "startColumnIndex": +startColumn - 1,
            "endColumnIndex": +endColumn
          },
          "top": {
            "style": "SOLID",
            "width": 1,
            "color": {
              "blue": 1.0
            },
          },
          "bottom": {
            "style": "SOLID",
            "width": 1,
            "color": {
              "blue": 1.0
            },
          },
          "left": {
            "style": "SOLID",
            "width": 1,
            "color": {
              "blue": 1.0
            },
          },
          "right": {
            "style": "SOLID",
            "width": 1,
            "color": {
              "blue": 1.0
            },
          },
          "innerHorizontal": {
            "style": "SOLID",
            "width": 1,
            "color": {
              "blue": 1.0
            },
          },
          "innerVertical": {
            "style": "SOLID",
            "width": 1,
            "color": {
              "blue": 1.0
            },
          },
        }
      }
    ]
  }
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Mike Steelson for the response. Your solution for batch updating the borders works.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply apply setBorder(and other functions) to a range:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Log")
    .getRange(1,1,5,5)
    .setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true,
        "green",SpreadsheetApp.BorderStyle.DASHED)
```